# Multiple Storage Accounts for Azure Log Integration

Tags: azure, logging

Can we use multiple storage accounts with Azure Log integration? i.e different accounts for App gateway, IaaS VMs , Azure AD etc.? What would be the best practice around this?
Also can we use a single Log integration instance be integrated with two different SIEM systems(Splunk and QRadar etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

We can use multiple storage accounts with the same Azure log integration instance. Navigate to c:\Program Files\Microsoft Azure Log Integration and then change the friendly name,storage account name and key as shown below.
Azlog source add  WAD  
Link for more information is below as well.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/security-azure-log-integration-get-started#integrate-azure-diagnostic-logging